# Fourier transform of 2D Gaussian kernel is not matching up with its counterpart in the spatial domain

Tags: python, image-processing, signal-processing, fft, convolution

We know the Fourier transform of a Gaussian filter is again Gaussian in the frequency domain, I have written the following method to build a Gaussian kernel:

```py
def get_gaussian(size, sigma):
  g_kernel = np.zeros((size,size))
  x_center = size // 2
  y_center = size // 2
  for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
      g_kernel[i,j] = np.exp(-((i - x_center)**2 + (j - y_center)**2) / (2*sigma**2))
  return 1/(2*np.pi * sigma**2)* g_kernel

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 10))
sigma = 20
g_spatial = get_gaussian(img2.shape[0],sigma)
plt.imshow(g_spatial)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 10))
g_frequnecy = fft.fftshift(fft.fft2(g_spatial))
plt.imshow(np.abs(g_frequnecy))

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 10))
g_spatial = get_gaussian(img2.shape[0],sigma / (np.sqrt(2) * np.pi))
plt.imshow(g_spatial)
```

The second and third Gaussians don't seem to match up at all. I will attach the pictures of all three Gaussian kernels below. I'm pretty sure I have calculated the variance of each Gaussian kernel such that they would match based on the 2D Fourier transform of a Gaussian kernel. Where have I made a mistake?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the frequency domain, the Gaussian has a sigma of `size / (2 * pi * sigma)`, with `size` the size of the image, and `sigma` the spatial-domain sigma. Yes, for a non-square image, an isotropic Gaussian in the spatial domain is not isotropic in the frequency domain.

Your computation `sigma / (np.sqrt(2) * np.pi)` is wrong. One quick way to tell it's not correct is that a larger sigma in the spatial domain also produces a larger sigma in the frequency domain using your computation. But we know that scaling up (==making larger) in the spatial domain scales the frequency domain down, as larger wavelengths have smaller frequencies.

Comment: Can you help me understand how the size of the image comes into the play here? Mathematically I can't seem to understand.

Comment: I now searched for it, and it says the sigma of the Gaussian is 1/(2 * pi * sigma) in the frequency domain, but again I don't see how the size of the image enters the equation.

Comment: @nothatcreative5 The frequency represented by each bin is related to the image size. Bin 1 corresponds to one period of length `size`, so frequency is `1/size`. Bin 2 is `2/size`, etc. In the spatial domain, the size of the Gaussian is not dependent on the image size, so for a larger image, the frequencies of that Gaussian are relatively higher (i.e. represented by later bins).

Comment: If I use Gaussian with (sigma) I mean this matlab filter (imgaussfilt(A,sigma)) ... now the filter domain is spatial or freuency? @CrisLuengo

Comment: @HayaAkkad `imgaussfilt` takes the spatial-domain sigma. If it happens to do computation in the frequency domain or not is irrelevant. Please read the documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgaussfilt.html